# Registering raster layers in Amazon RDS PostgreSQL using enable_out_db parameter

Tags: raster, postgis, database, parameters, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance (v.11) that I'm currently storing vector data in. I also have a lot of raster layers in AWS S3 that are COG geotiffs. I'd like to register them in the database to have them visible to end users to find. I've tried to figure out how to set the `enable_outdb_rasters` parameter to True, but it only works at the session level. My users are mainly accessing through QGIS desktop app, and don't have a way/knowledge to send a session-specific parameter SQL statement through the app when they connect to the DB. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use Geoserver? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/cog/cog.html  ImageMosaic indexer configuration could make it easy for QGIS end users.

Comment: Thanks @mapperz - this does look helpful. I was hoping to not have to standup any more servers/extra applications and just register them directly in the database for ease (and less overhead maintenance). This might be a good secondary solution!